# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' when training a CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, image-segmentation

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am training 3d dense CNN. I have 12GB GPU and 128GB RAM. The training happens on GPU but the cross-validation happens on RAM because of which I get the above error in between the training (CV utilizes all RAM). I want both training and CV to use GPU resources.

The model has around 3M parameters and I am using a batch size of 1 (both for training and CV).

I am using the following commands to specify GPU -

```
os.environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEIVCES] = '0'

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.allow_soft_placement = True

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```